# Itemscontrol in tabcontrol?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, itemscontrol

i have the following code to be implemented into my xaml file.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xDoc}, XPath=targets/target/antcall/@target}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource UnderscoresConverter}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

i already have a tab control under my window1. where and how should i implement this itemscontrol? sorry i am a beginner in wpf.

EDIT:
I have a grid control under my tab control too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't quite get what you are trying to do.If you are trying to add your itemscontrol to the tabcontrol,see the below code

```
 <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Page 1">
                <Grid>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xDoc}, XPath=targets/target/antcall/@target}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource UnderscoresConverter}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Page 2">
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```